# how to cover the unit interval by using shift operators

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Consider the following partition of $[0,1)$:
$$P:=\left\{
[0,\frac{1}{2^n}), [\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{2}{2^n}),[\frac{2}{2^n},\frac{3}{2^n}), [\frac3{2^n},\frac{4}{2^n}), \cdots, [\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},1)\right\}.$$
Consider shift-operators $T_k:t\mapsto (t+k)\mod 1$.
Let $I:=\cup_i A_i$, $A_i \in P$, with $m(I)=\frac{1}{2^j}$, where $m$ stands for the Lebesgue measure and $j\le n$.
I want to choose some $T_k$'s such that $\cup_k T_k(I) =[0,1)$.
How many $T_k$'s do I need to take? Of course, it is less than $2^n+1$ but I am wondering whether I can find a better estimate.

Comment: What has this got to do with group theory?